# MVC4 - Model: Method must have a return type?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

i use MVC4 visual studio to create a project.
What i try to do is a sql instruction "Insert Into" to my database in Models.

I have this code below and the error is that the **"method must have a return type"** .

i dont know what i have to write..

Error: infouploadimage have a red underline

someone can give me a hand with this pls?

Code in Model:

```
 public class UploadImage
     {
         public string Title { get; set; }
         public string ImagePath { get; set; }

         public infouploadimage(string title, string imagepath) 
         {
             Title=title;
             ImagePath=imagepath;

             string connection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;

             using (SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection(connection))
             {
                 string query = "Insert Into myimage (PicTitle, PicPath) Values(@title, @imagepath)";

                 SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connect);
                 command.Parameters.AddWithValue("title", Title);
                 command.Parameters.AddWithValue("imagepath", ImagePath);
                 connect.Open();
                 command.ExecuteNonQuery();
             } 


         }
     }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method obviously lacks part of its definition - the return type, `void` in this case:

```
public void infouploadimage(string title, string imagepath)
```

Answer (score 1):

As what you've tried is not a `constructor`, you're missing the return type. If it's unnecessary for you, just set it to `void`:

```
public void infouploadimage(string title, string imagepath)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have error in decaration:

```
     public infouploadimage(string title, string imagepath) 
     {
```

You can correct using something like this:

```
     public void infouploadimage(string title, string imagepath) 
     {
```